# Entity-Attribute-Value Model Insert Update Read All Attributes and their associated Values SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, entity-relationship, entity-attribute-value

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have an E-A-V Database model that I need to be able to  perform crud operations on. I am willing to use any combination of user defined functions to accomplish the task. The datatypes are individual tables with their respective values. I created a function to get the table name associated with an attribute - so I know what table the value should be in. 
I have created a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=5ba9a7b94414fb88832002a61e74708c) of the design and below have the diagram (there are more datatypes but this is for brevity).

The result I would like to get for any given entity is Attribute Name, Value, Min, Max  - given that columns are named the same and data types are different - not sure how that will effect the results.

I am not sure if my model is the best way to do this, I thought about storing the values as text and use casting when storing and retrieving via stored procedures or functions - I will need to do some value comparisons on the data. Perhaps this design might make it easier to query and update .

> Any guidance or examples is really appreciated.

1 Entity can have multiple attributes and each defined attribute can have only one datatype.
1 Attribute can belong to many Entities - the values for each attribute are unique to that attribute.

Entity 1 Has Attributes 1 through 5.
Entity 2 Has Attributes 1 through 5 (The attribute values can be different than the values in entity 1).
Entity 3 Has Attributes 1, 4, 8 ,9 , 10,11, 20.

I have stumbled across this concept: perhaps a good approach.
[Database Design: Recursive Many to Many Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721813/database-design-recursive-many-to-many-relationships)

[image: E_R Diagram of EAV]

Comment: Basically with EAV you are re-building a database management system inside your database. Whatever you do its going to be quite ugly. e.g. selecting a row of data is going to need N joins for N columns. Sometimes EAV is the right way to go, but bear in mind that its a difficult path.

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid (point #3)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) for a discussion of why EAV is really really bad, and see [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) for a true horror story of an EAV system design that ruined a thriving company.

Comment: @marc_s I value and respect your input; I agree EAV is complex. The attributes that I have are quite lengthy and not all are known at design time and future additions will be made. 1 entity many attribs (not the same as others) For ex. requirements,there is the property and value (which could be text, Integer,decimal ,etc..)  i.e. requirement_Id, name, value [ValueType(text, Int,decimal)] I need to be able to perform comparisons on this collection. Basically I am trying to implement a requirements table and validate other data against those requirements. Flexible enough to add requirements.

Comment: Just wondering if you might need to investigate other approaches, e.g. possibly storing those varying attributes in XML or JSON or something like that - rather than the EAV approach.

Comment: @marc_s yes I had looked at those approaches; having to query against values if they exist in an xml file (my experience with xml inside db is non existent ) and I have a short time to implement something. None of the methods is appetizing to me , all my reading has turned up 'they are bad - just each has a trade-off in bad' - I really like simple, unfortunately in this situation I seem to be boxed in.